# How do I un-nest multiple sets of data and set them as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, nested

I am trying to bring this data from an api into a data frame however some of the data is nested under another one. So for example I would like to have each stat like 'passing_att' as its own column. But it is nested under 'passing' which 'passing' and 'rushing' and 'receiving' is all nested under 'stats'. I can bring just 'passing' into a data frame which would show 'passing_att' and the rest of the 'passing' data but then I don't have names and all the other data I would like.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJCur.png)

Comment: paste the json object as an image can't be easily replicated.

Comment: Share the code of your as text instead of an image.

Comment: See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/)

Answer (score 0):

The correct word is to 'flatten' a JSON object. There are many ways to do this. You could use the `flatten_json` pip package or write your own function to do this. Though for your specific use case, you could use the `json_normalize()` function from the pandas library because you are trying to flatten a list of JSON objects that can easily be converted into a pandas dataframe.

Once you have the nested JSON object as show below (performed in your code):

```py
json_list = json.loads(response.text)
```

Use the following code to flatten it:

```py
df = pandas.json_normalize(json_list)
```

You will get all the nested columns flattened into a single level dataframe separated by a period. For example, the `passing_att` attribute cann be accessed via the column name `'stats.passing.passing_att'`. You can change the separator by passing the `sep` parameter to the `json_normalize` function. For example, if you want to use a hyphen as the separator, you can do so by passing the following parameter to the `json_normalize` function:

```py
df = pandas.json_normalize(json_list, sep='-')
```

If you want to select only a few columns, you can pass a list of column names to the dataframe's `[]` operator. For example, if you want to select only the `player_name`, `position`, `passing_att` and `passing_cmp` columns, you can do so by using the following code:

```py
df = df[['player_name', 'position', 'stats.passing.passing_att', 'stats.passing.passing_cmp']]
```

Comment: Also, in future kindly put the code here as a snippet in your question instead of posting an image. You will get answers more easily. The format of JSON can vary the method of flattening it.